# How to filter all Apache URL containing string but not containing a substring

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to filter all clients (using .htaccess) who try to access addresses containing for instance `path=\` in the URL, but not those URL's that contain `_wpnonce=1234567890`.

> The logic is: block all but those who also have the _wpnonce
>   parameter.

The blocking, without testing if it contains the substring looks like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (menu|mod|path|tag)\=\.?/? [NC,OR]
```

Is there a way to also include my substring negation there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation says that the pattern is a Perl-compatible regular expression, so you should be able to use a negative lookahead assertion:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?!.*_wpnonce=1234567890).*(menu|mod|path|tag)\=\.?/? [NC,OR]
```

though it might be clearer to put it in a separate `RewriteCond`, provided you can get all the `[OR]`s to work out. If it weren't for the `[OR]`s, you could just write:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !_wpnonce=1234567890 [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (menu|mod|path|tag)\=\.?/? [NC]
```

Comment: I have used the second version and it works. As the list was longer (has more blocking lines) I had to put it first, otherwise it was ignoring the ones before it. There are other definitions after this, also.

`
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !_wpnonce=[a-z0-9]{10} [NC]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (menu|mod|path|tag)\=\.?/? [NC,OR]
`