# Javascript Regular Expression for non-image url

Tags: javascript, regex, url

In JavaScript, I want to extract a non-image url from a string e.g.

> http://example.com
>
> http://example.com/a.png
>
> http://www.example.ccom/acd.php
>
> http://www.example.com/b.jpg etc.

I would like to extract 1st and 3rd (non-image) URLs and ignore 2nd and 4th (image) URLs.

I tried the following which did not work

```
(https?:)?\/\/?[^\'"<>]+?^(\.(jpe?g|gif|png))
```

Which is the modification of the following Image URL Regular Expression (RE) to whom I added ^() (for not) for above snippet

```
(https?:)?//?[^\'"<>]+?\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)
```

Note: The RE in above examples is case-sensitive, if any clue for making RE case-insensitive

Comment: Why not try to match those images and then reject them if they match? The syntax `^()` doesn't mean 'not', it means newline, then tries to match what's inside.

Comment: an option could be to use curl to check whether the url is an image

Comment: where to negate? If you could please provide modified version of above snippet?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [negative lookahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749437/regular-expression-negative-lookahead) like [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15144664/regex-to-retrieve-all-urls-not-containing-specific-string) [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304930/how-to-filter-all-apache-url-containing-string-but-not-containing-a-substring) It will exclude anything with the string
assuming your urls are newline delimited like your example, something like this should work

```
(?!.*(jpg|jpeg|gif|png).*).*
```

EDIT: it looks like my example doesn't work, hopefully it is pointing oyu in the right direction at least

Comment: Even if it worked, it would not work on urls like `http://example.com/gifts/index` because `gif` will match in `gifts`. Ideally a negative lookbehind would be what's needed, but JS doesn't support that,

Comment: Hi Eru, thanks for the answer but this did not work for me as `(https?:)?\/\/?[^\'"<>]+(?!.*(jpg|jpeg|gif|png).*).*`  returns true for both either image or non-image url. May be I am missing your point that where to use your negation snippet.

Answer (score 0):

first removing the images:

```
var tmp = text.replace(/https?:\/\/[\S]+\.(png|jpeg|jpg|gif)/gi, '');
```

and then matching:

```
var m = tmp.match(/https?:\/\/[\S]+/gi);
console.log(m);
```